count the number of minutes from the start time
I have a vector with minutes, seconds and fractions of seconds
tm <- structure(c("49:03.3", "49:05.5", "49:07.8", "49:10.1", "49:12.3", "49:14.6", 
                  "49:16.8", "49:19.1", "49:21.4", "49:23.6", "49:25.9", "49:28.2", 
                  "49:30.4", "49:32.7", "49:34.9", "49:37.2", "49:39.5", "49:41.7", 
                  "49:44.0", "49:46.2", "49:48.5", "49:50.8", "49:53.0", "49:55.3", 
                  "49:57.6", "49:59.8", "50:02.1", "50:04.4", "50:06.6", "50:08.9", 
                  "50:11.2", "50:13.4", "50:15.7", "50:18.0", "50:20.2", "50:22.5", 
                  "50:24.7", "50:27.0", "50:29.3", "50:31.5", "50:33.8", "50:36.0", 
                  "50:38.3", "50:40.6", "50:42.8", "50:45.1", "50:47.4", "50:49.6", 
                  "50:51.9", "50:54.1", "50:56.4", "50:58.7", "51:01.0", "51:03.2", 
                  "51:05.5", "51:07.7", "51:10.0", "51:12.3", "51:14.5", "51:16.8", 
                  "51:19.0", "51:21.4", "51:23.6", "51:25.9", "51:28.1", "51:30.4", 
                  "51:32.7", "51:34.9", "51:37.2", "51:39.4", "51:41.7", "51:44.0", 
                  "51:46.2", "51:48.5", "51:50.8", "51:53.0", "51:55.3", "51:57.5", 
                  "51:59.8", "52:02.1", "52:04.3", "52:06.6", "52:08.8", "52:11.1", 
                  "52:13.4", "52:15.6", "52:17.9", "52:20.2", "52:22.4", "52:24.7", 
                  "52:26.9", "52:29.2", "52:31.5", "52:33.7", "52:36.0", "52:38.3", 
                  "52:40.6", "52:42.8", "52:45.1", "52:47.3", "52:49.6", "52:51.9", 
                  "52:54.1", "52:56.4", "52:58.6", "53:00.9", "53:03.2", "53:05.4", 
                  "53:07.7", "53:10.0", "53:12.2", "53:14.5", "53:16.7", "53:19.0", 
                  "53:21.3", "53:23.5", "53:25.8", "53:28.0", "53:30.3", "53:32.6", 
                  "53:34.9", "53:37.1", "53:39.4", "53:41.6", "53:43.9", "53:46.2", 
                  "53:48.4", "53:50.7", "53:52.9", "53:55.3", "53:57.5", "53:59.8", 
                  "54:02.0", "54:04.3", "54:06.6", "54:08.8", "54:11.1", "54:13.3", 
                  "54:15.6", "54:17.9", "54:20.1", "54:22.4", "54:24.7", "54:26.9", 
                  "54:29.2", "54:31.4", "54:33.7", "54:36.0", "54:38.2", "54:40.5", 
                  "54:42.8", "54:45.0", "54:47.3", "54:49.5", "54:51.8", "54:54.1", 
                  "54:56.3", "54:58.6", "55:00.8", "55:03.1", "55:05.4", "55:07.6", 
                  "55:09.9", "55:12.2", "55:14.5", "55:16.7", "55:19.0", "55:21.2", 
                  "55:23.5", "55:25.8", "55:28.0", "55:30.3", "55:32.6", "55:34.8", 
                  "55:37.1", "55:39.3", "55:41.6", "55:43.9", "55:46.1", "55:48.4", 
                  "55:50.6", "55:52.9", "55:55.2", "55:57.5", "55:59.7", "56:02.0", 
                  "56:04.2", "56:06.5", "56:08.8", "56:11.0", "56:13.3", "56:15.5", 
                  "56:17.8", "56:20.1", "56:22.3", "56:24.6", "56:26.9", "56:29.2", 
                  "56:31.4", "56:33.7", "56:35.9", "56:38.2", "56:40.5", "56:42.7", 
                  "56:45.0", "56:47.3", "56:49.5", "56:51.8", "56:54.0", "56:56.3", 
                  "56:58.6", "57:00.8", "57:03.1", "57:05.3", "57:07.6", "57:09.9", 
                  "57:12.1", "57:14.4", "57:16.7", "57:18.9", "57:21.2", "57:23.4", 
                  "57:25.7", "57:28.0", "57:30.2", "57:32.5", "57:34.7", "57:37.0", 
                  "57:39.3", "57:41.5", "57:43.8", "57:46.1", "57:48.4", "57:50.6", 
                  "57:52.9", "57:55.1", "57:57.4", "57:59.7", "58:01.9", "58:04.2", 
                  "58:06.5", "58:08.7", "58:11.0", "58:13.2", "58:15.5", "58:17.8", 
                  "58:20.1", "58:22.3", "58:24.5", "58:26.8", "58:29.1", "58:31.4", 
                  "58:33.6", "58:35.9", "58:38.1", "58:40.4", "58:42.7", "58:44.9", 
                  "58:47.2", "58:49.5", "58:51.7", "58:54.0", "58:56.2", "58:58.5", 
                  "59:00.8", "59:03.1", "59:05.3", "59:07.6", "59:09.9", "59:12.1", 
                  "59:14.4", "59:16.6", "59:18.9", "59:21.2", "59:23.4", "59:25.7", 
                  "59:27.9", "59:30.2", "59:32.5", "59:34.7", "59:37.0", "59:39.3", 
                  "59:41.5", "59:43.8", "59:46.0", "59:48.3", "59:50.6", "59:52.8", 
                  "59:55.1", "59:57.3", "59:59.6", "00:01.9", "00:04.1", "00:06.4", 
                  "00:08.7", "00:10.9", "00:13.2", "00:15.4", "00:17.7", "00:20.0", 
                  "00:22.3", "00:24.5", "00:26.8", "00:29.1", "00:31.3", "00:33.6", 
                  "00:35.8", "00:38.1", "00:40.4", "00:42.6", "00:44.9", "00:47.1", 
                  "00:49.4", "00:51.7", "00:54.0", "00:56.2", "00:58.5", "01:00.7", 
                  "01:03.0", "01:05.3", "01:07.5", "01:09.8", "01:12.0", "01:14.3", 
                  "01:16.6", "01:18.8", "01:21.1", "01:23.4", "01:25.6", "01:27.9", 
                  "01:30.1", "01:32.4", "01:34.7", "01:37.0", "01:39.2", "01:41.5", 
                  "01:43.8", "01:46.0", "01:48.3", "01:50.5", "01:52.8", "01:55.1", 
                  "01:57.3", "01:59.6", "02:01.9", "02:04.1", "02:06.4", "02:08.6", 
                  "02:10.9", "02:13.2", "02:15.4", "02:17.7", "02:19.9", "02:22.2", 
                  "02:24.5", "02:26.7", "02:29.0", "02:31.3", "02:33.5", "02:35.8", 
                  "02:38.0", "02:40.3", "02:42.6", "02:44.8", "02:47.1", "02:49.3", 
                  "02:51.6", "02:53.9", "02:56.2", "02:58.4", "03:00.7", "03:03.0", 
                  "03:05.2", "03:07.5", "03:09.7", "03:12.0"))

I want to count the number of minutes that have passed since counting from the first value
library(lubridate)
q <- ms(tm)
round(as.numeric(q - q[1]) / 60, 2)

But inside the vector a new hour starts and it breaks my code starting from index 292
round(as.numeric(q - q[1]) / 60,2) 
  [1]   0.00   0.04   0.07   0.11   0.15   0.19   0.22   0.26   0.30   0.34   0.38   0.42
 [13]   0.45   0.49   0.53   0.57   0.60   0.64   0.68   0.72   0.75   0.79   0.83   0.87
 [25]   0.90   0.94   0.98   1.02   1.05   1.09   1.13   1.17   1.21   1.25   1.28   1.32
 [37]   1.36   1.40   1.43   1.47   1.51   1.55   1.58   1.62   1.66   1.70   1.73   1.77
 [49]   1.81   1.85   1.89   1.92   1.96   2.00   2.04   2.07   2.11   2.15   2.19   2.22
 [61]   2.26   2.30   2.34   2.38   2.41   2.45   2.49   2.53   2.56   2.60   2.64   2.68
 [73]   2.72   2.75   2.79   2.83   2.87   2.90   2.94   2.98   3.02   3.06   3.09   3.13
 [85]   3.17   3.20   3.24   3.28   3.32   3.36   3.39   3.43   3.47   3.51   3.54   3.58
 [97]   3.62   3.66   3.70   3.73   3.77   3.81   3.85   3.88   3.92   3.96   4.00   4.04
[109]   4.07   4.11   4.15   4.19   4.22   4.26   4.30   4.34   4.38   4.41   4.45   4.49
[121]   4.53   4.56   4.60   4.64   4.68   4.72   4.75   4.79   4.83   4.87   4.90   4.94
[133]   4.98   5.02   5.06   5.09   5.13   5.17   5.20   5.24   5.28   5.32   5.36   5.39
[145]   5.43   5.47   5.51   5.54   5.58   5.62   5.66   5.69   5.73   5.77   5.81   5.85
[157]   5.88   5.92   5.96   6.00   6.04   6.07   6.11   6.15   6.19   6.22   6.26   6.30
[169]   6.34   6.38   6.41   6.45   6.49   6.53   6.56   6.60   6.64   6.68   6.71   6.75
[181]   6.79   6.83   6.86   6.90   6.94   6.98   7.02   7.05   7.09   7.13   7.17   7.20
[193]   7.24   7.28   7.32   7.36   7.39   7.43   7.47   7.51   7.54   7.58   7.62   7.66
[205]   7.69   7.73   7.77   7.81   7.84   7.88   7.92   7.96   8.00   8.03   8.07   8.11
[217]   8.15   8.19   8.22   8.26   8.30   8.34   8.37   8.41   8.45   8.49   8.52   8.56
[229]   8.60   8.64   8.68   8.71   8.75   8.79   8.83   8.86   8.90   8.94   8.98   9.01
[241]   9.05   9.09   9.13   9.16   9.20   9.24   9.28   9.32   9.35   9.39   9.43   9.47
[253]   9.50   9.54   9.58   9.62   9.66   9.69   9.73   9.77   9.81   9.85   9.88   9.92
[265]   9.96  10.00  10.03  10.07  10.11  10.15  10.19  10.22  10.26  10.30  10.34  10.37
[277]  10.41  10.45  10.49  10.52  10.56  10.60  10.64  10.68  10.71  10.75  10.79  10.82
[289]  10.86  10.90  10.94 -49.02 -48.99 -48.95 -48.91 -48.87 -48.84 -48.80 -48.76 -48.72
[301] -48.68 -48.65 -48.61 -48.57 -48.53 -48.49 -48.46 -48.42 -48.38 -48.34 -48.31 -48.27
[313] -48.23 -48.19 -48.16 -48.12 -48.08 -48.04 -48.01 -47.97 -47.93 -47.89 -47.86 -47.82
[325] -47.78 -47.74 -47.70 -47.66 -47.63 -47.59 -47.55 -47.52 -47.48 -47.44 -47.40 -47.36
[337] -47.33 -47.29 -47.25 -47.21 -47.17 -47.14 -47.10 -47.06 -47.02 -46.99 -46.95 -46.91
[349] -46.87 -46.84 -46.80 -46.76 -46.72 -46.68 -46.65 -46.61 -46.57 -46.53 -46.50 -46.46
[361] -46.42 -46.38 -46.34 -46.31 -46.27 -46.23 -46.20 -46.16 -46.12 -46.08 -46.04 -46.01
[373] -45.97 -45.93 -45.89 -45.86

How can I get a vector that counts the number of elapsed minutes from the first value, regardless of transitions to a new hour?

For this example data, you can do: round(as.numeric(q - q[1]) / 60, 2) + 60 * (q<q[1])

Since you've got a vector of times spanning only 60 minutes, you can add 60 minutes to the vector conditional on the time value being less than the starting time.
round(as.numeric(q - q[1]) / 60, 2) + 60 * (q<q[1])


  [1]  0.00  0.04  0.07  0.11  0.15  0.19  0.22  0.26  0.30  0.34  0.38
 [12]  0.42  0.45  0.49  0.53  0.57  0.60  0.64  0.68  0.72  0.75  0.79
...
[287] 10.79 10.82 10.86 10.90 10.94 10.98 11.01 11.05 11.09 11.13 11.16
[298] 11.20 11.24 11.28 11.32 11.35 11.39 11.43 11.47 11.51 11.54 11.58
[309] 11.62 11.66 11.69 11.73 11.77 11.81 11.84 11.88 11.92 11.96 11.99
[320] 12.03 12.07 12.11 12.14 12.18 12.22 12.26 12.30 12.34 12.37 12.41
[331] 12.45 12.48 12.52 12.56 12.60 12.64 12.67 12.71 12.75 12.79 12.83
[342] 12.86 12.90 12.94 12.98 13.01 13.05 13.09 13.13 13.16 13.20 13.24
[353] 13.28 13.32 13.35 13.39 13.43 13.47 13.50 13.54 13.58 13.62 13.66
[364] 13.69 13.73 13.77 13.80 13.84 13.88 13.92 13.96 13.99 14.03 14.07
[375] 14.11 14.14

We need to surround q<q[1] by round brackets here () to ensure the comparison is executed first (before multiplying by 60), otherwise we'd be adding a logical vector instead of 60 (try 60 * q < q[1]). Type help(Syntax) for details on the order of operator syntax and precedence in R.
Also, whenever a logical vector (TRUE/FALSE) meets an arithmetic operation (+, -. *. /), it is coerced into numeric. See: section 2.4 of "An Introduction to R".
